# trouble getting sublime to execute with linux terminal

Tags: linux, unix, ubuntu, terminal, sublimetext2

I know a few similar questions have been asked, but none seemed to help me so here it goes.  I am trying to get sublime to run when I use 'subl' in the Linux terminal but I just cannot get it to work.  I tried

```
sudo ln -s /Applications/Sublime\ Text\ 2/sublime_text usr/bin/subl
```

and that did create the file correctly so it seems, but then when I use the subl command it says 'No command 'subl' found.'  Now I have rvm installed, so that may make a difference.  I also tried 'usr/local/bin/subl' and the result was the same.  I even used the rvmsudo afterward with the above command and it said file already created, and yet the subl command still does not work.  What am I missing here?  Keep in mind that I am a)new to linux b)new to sublime.  Running ubuntu 12.10 if it matters

Comment: rvm lets you control multiple ruby/rails versions.  It should not impact your sublime install.

Comment: Also, *Applications/Sublime Text 2* is not the right folder for linux, I think that command is for Macs.  On my computer sublime was installed at */usr/lib*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using Linux Mint 13, but should be similar for you. `cd` into */usr/bin*.  There should a file called *sublime-text-2*. Copy that file and name *subl*.  Then `subl` command should be usable in the terminal.

```
cd /usr/bin
sudo cp sublime-text-2 subl
```

Just in case, here is the contents of the file:

```
#!/bin/bash

/usr/lib/sublime-text-2/sublime_text --class=sublime-text-2 "$@"
```

Comment: Alright I looked in usr/bin and it had 2 files `sublime_text` and `sublime_text~`
so as instructed, I executed the commands
`cd /usr/bin
sudo cp sublime_text subl`
Then it told me this: `cp: not writing through dangling symlink 'subl'`
So does that mean I need to go back and delete those files I initially created with the `sudo ln -s` command?

Comment: Yes.  The symlink is broken because it is not pointing to anything.

Comment: so then I would do `rm usr/bin/subl`?
Edit: Bingo! Thanks so much this finally worked!

Answer (score 0):

Brotherman, you have to update your path. It's probably easier than mucking around with `ln -s` softlinks. Go into your `~/.bashrc` and at the bottom somewhere add `export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/your/binary`.

Then all you should have to do is `. ~/.bashrc` and voila!

Comment: Alright so I added `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin/subl` to the .bashrc file.  Is that what you meant? And then I typed `. ~/.bashrc` into the terminal, hit enter, and restarted the terminal. But `subl` was still not recognized as a command.  I guess I'm not even sure what you mean by a path to the binary. Is that similar to the .exe of a program in windows?  I literally started using Linux for the first time yesterday.

Comment: `path` is a list of directories in which the OS searches for binaries. If you `echo $PATH` you should see the correct path to your binary.

Comment: So this is what I get when I type in `echo $PATH`:
/home/aaron/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385@railstutorial/bin:/home/aaron/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385@global/bin:/home/aaron/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/bin:/home/aaron/.rvm/bin:/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games


     Now, with that information, what EXACTLY am I supposed to do?

Answer (score 0):

I think you had a typo. It should be

```
sudo ln -s /Applications/Sublime\ Text\ 2/sublime_text /usr/bin/subl
```

Notice the `/` before `usr`. If you tell terminal `usr/bin/subl`, it'll take it as a relative path and create it in reference to the directory you were on when you executed this command.

Comment: When I typed that in, it said it failed to create symbolic link because the file exists so that must have been what I typed in the first place, just not in this question.  In fact, I probably did it both ways just to try to get something to work.

Comment: Ok. But it's really an obvious typo. Couldn't help pointing it out. :)

Comment: You could try `ls -al /usr/bin` and see if `subl` is there and where it's linked to.

Comment: it says `subl -> /home/aaron/Applications/Sublime Text 2/sublime_text`
By the way, wtf is up with file structure browsing in Linux?  If I go to the home folder, there is no folder named aaron. Also, if it matters, right below that first entry, it says `sublime_text` and then `sublime_text~` if that matters

Comment: Your "Home" folder is located at */home/username/*.  Irregardless, the symlink is not pointing to the right location.

Comment: sublime_text~ is a backup file because somewhere down the road you edited sublime_text

Comment: delete the existing `subl` link with `sudo rm /usr/bin/subl`, then try again. Make sure the file `/Applications/Sublime\ Text\ 2/sublime_text` file exists.