# "subl" command not found

Tags: terminal, sublimetext2

When I try to edit a file, like `~/.gemrc`, in the terminal, I get this error:

```
$ subl ~/.gemrc
-bash: subl: command not found
```

Comment: The entire premise of your question is incorrect, and I’ve edited your question to reflect that, but feel free to re-edit if you wish.

Comment: What is your operating system?

Comment: If Linux, `subl` alias does not work by default.  Probably the same for Windows.  It's usually `sublime_text`.  Again if Linux, see this q/a for setting up `subl`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14833771/trouble-getting-sublime-to-execute-with-linux-terminal/14863752#14863752

Answer (score 2):

Follow the instructions [here](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/osx_command_line.html).

If that doesn't work and you are using RVM, run: `ln -s "/Applications/Sublime Text 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" ~/.rvm/bin/subl`

Note that in both of these commands, it's assumed that Sublime Text 2 is installed in your Applications directory. If its installed elsewhere change your command accordingly.

Then, enter `export EDITOR='subl -w'` to enable editing with the `subl` command.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have "[Sublime Text 2](http://www.sublimetext.com)" installed? It's a text editor and is what the `subl` command would launch.

Since you don't have Sublime, you could use [`vim`](http://www.vim.org/about.php), which is installed on Mac OS, and is a very powerful text editor, but it does have a learning curve.

There's also [`nano`](http://www.nano-editor.org), which will do for simple text editing purposes Try entering `man nano` at the command-line for more information. Try entering `nano ~/.gemrc` to create the file in question.

It sounds like you're not really familiar with your computer or its operating system. Trying to learn to program without understanding it is going to put you at a disadvantage, because languages like Ruby, Python and Perl tend to be used for a lot of OS-level code plus web and communications, which is a "heap of learning".

I'd recommend spending some time learning about the basic commands of your command-line, and get familiar with either vim or download Sublime and try it. (And, if you use Sublime or vim regularly, encourage the author by purchasing a copy -- they're very good editors and we want to keep those sort of tools around.)

Comment: I have Sublime Text 2 installed and still got the error message shown above. If I need to create a .gemrc file, what application do i use?

Comment: If you have Sublime Text 2 installed, then you didn't install the command-line tool `subl` or it's not installed in your path, or you didn't modify your path to point to where it's installed. And, I said what tools you could use in the answer.